# Problems with tensorflow python

Tags: python, tensorflow

I installed tensorflow on my mac but when I try to import it on my jupyter notebook this error appears:

***KeyError: "Couldn't find field google.protobuf.EnumDescriptorProto.EnumReservedRange.start"***

I've checked the version both protobuf and tensorflow and I have the latest. The same for python.
Can anyone help me please? Thanks.

Comment: Look into this- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14689

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem above but now when I run the code I got this problem. [https://i.stack.imgur.com/krTSB.png][1]